# Convert Rhino Mock to NSubstitute

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks, nsubstitute

currently I am changing some implementation of Rhino Mock to NSubstitute. Now I have some difficulty here.
could someone help me ?

```
            var provider = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IProvider>();
        provider.Stub(e => e.InitMethod(Arg<Info>.Is.Anything, "ABC")).WhenCalled(
            o =>
            {
                validProvidersDto.ExportFolder = (o.Arguments[0] as Info).Name;
                o.ReturnValue = validProvidersDto;
            }).Return(validProvidersDto);
```

So the logik is: when InitMethod has been call via the provider stub. the code in WhenCalled will execute and modifies sth. and after that it returns sth.

Now I did change it to NSubstitute but its not compartible

```
            var provider = Substitute.For<IProvider>();
        provider.When(a => a.InitMethod(Arg.Any<Info>(), "ABC")).Do(
            o =>
            {
                validProvidersDto.ExportFolder = (o.Arguments[0] as Info).Name;
                o.ReturnValue = validProvidersDto;
            }).Returns(validProvidersDto);
```

I do not know how to convert correctly this WhenCalled from Rhino Mock to NSubstitute.

Appreciate for your help!

Comment: Question is currently unclear. `sth`?

Comment: What is the current and the expected behavior.

Comment: Let's provide how looks IProvider.

Comment: provide IProivder and validProvidersDto object, what is expected of this testing, so we can help you

Comment: sth. means the code inside WhenCalled Function. I am afraid that I can´t give any further information according to IProvider and validProvidersDto since they are somehow related to the company rules. Nevertheless the focus here is how to convert the WhenCalled Method from Rhino Mock to NSubstitute. The information inside the WhenCalled method is currently irreleveant. What I know so far is convert from "Arg<Info>.Is.AnyThing" to "Arg.Any<Info>()" and "MockRepository.GenerateStub" to "Substitute.For". I assuming that NSubstitute does not offer the identical function for "WhenCalled" case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you need using [a `Returns` callback](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-from-function/):

```
var provider = Substitute.For<IProvider>();
provider.InitMethod(Arg.Any<Info>(), "ABC").Returns(
    o => {
        validProvidersDto.ExportFolder = o.Arg<Info>().Name;
        return validProvidersDto;
    });
```